# Assign empty string to php variable

Tags: php

Just need help fixing this php code

```
if ($cmtx_set_name_value == "anonymous")             
{
   $cmtx_set_name_value = ""
}
```

thanks

Comment: What's wrong with it? It looks like it does what your titles says.

Comment: Seems valid code, except you're missing a `;` at the end of your statement...

Comment: put semicolon after the assignment

Comment: the answer is -> [here](http://www.php.net/docs.php)

Comment: Question is, What error are you getting? I can't see any problem except a missing semi-colon as everyone else says...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding ; after the assignment.

```
$cmtx_set_name_value = "";
```

Comment: thanks - that's what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

your code is work fine just put  ;  to end of line

```
if ($cmtx_set_name_value == "anonymous"){
$cmtx_set_name_value = "" ; }
```

Comment: thanks - that's what I was missing